# ADOMD.NET connection string with user id and password

Tags: asp.net, ssas, adomd.net, asp.net-authentication, asp.net-authorization

From asp.net web application connecting the SSAS cube.  Need to pass user credentials to the connection string. Web application is authenticated with windows identity.  Web application users doesn't have access to SSAS, need to access SSAS with a service account credentials.  SSAS service is not exposed in http.

Is there any way to pass the user credentials in ADOMD.NET connection string ?

Comment: You could take a look at this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.adomdconnection.connectionstring.aspx

Comment: Referred the link, Authenticated User is no longer supported,whats the alternate option.

Comment: I do not think you can use credentials in an ADOMD.NET connection string (except when it is used to access via http(s)). What you could try is to let your service run under an account having access to the cube, or somehow impersonate an account like this. However, I do not know how the impersonation would look in code.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the Asp.NET web page and retrieved the data from cube to asp.net/MVC page. You need to create an application pool in IIS server first and connect the ssas to IIS server using windows account credentials.  In ASP.NET use local host as the DATA SOURCE in connection string.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6562/Cubes-MDX-Analysis-Services-and-ADOMD-in-C

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28290/Microsoft-Analysis-Services-Displaying-a-grid